# FermiPasta-Ulam problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, systems-of-equations

Consider $H(q,p) = \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n+1} {(p_j^2 + (q_{j}-q_{j-1})^2)}$

$H(q,p) $ is the Hamiltonian considered in the FermiPasta-Ulam problem. Consider canonical transformation

$Q = \sqrt{\frac{2}{n+1}} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} {q_{k}}$ $sin(\frac{kjn\pi}{n+1})$,
$P = \sqrt{\frac{2}{n+1}} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} {p_{k}}$ $sin(\frac{kjn\pi}{n+1})$

Show that $H(Q,P) = \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} {(P_j^2 + \omega^2 Q_{j}^2)}$. I could not obtain $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} {(Q_{j}-Q_{j-1})^2 }= \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} {\omega^2 Q_{j}^2} $. I used trigonometric identities to simplify the computation, but I could not get $H(Q,P) = \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} {(P_j^2 + \omega^2 Q_{j}^2)}$, so could you guys help me to do this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Note that one is not supposed to prove $(Q_{j}-Q_{j-1})^2 = \omega^2 Q_{j}^2 $ but $\sum\limits_j(q_{j}-q_{j-1})^2 = \omega^2\sum\limits_j Q_{j}^2 $.

Comment: sorry for the typo error

Comment: You still must replace some `Q`s by `q`s.

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Answer (score 2):

> To summarize, this is precisely the kind of task discrete Fourier transform was invented for, I believe...

Let us first see how the $p$ part of the Hamiltonian is transformed, before looking at the $q$ part.
Thus, forgetting some irrelevant factors, first consider
$$
h_1(p)=\sum_kp_k^2.
$$
The crucial remark is that, for some suitable family of parameters $s$,
$$
h_1(p)=\sum_jP_j^2,\quad\text{where}\quad P_j=\sum_kp_ks(kj).
$$
When does this happen? Well, note that, for every $j$,
$$
P_j^2=\sum_k\sum_\ell p_kp_\ell s(kj)s(\ell j),
$$
hence
$$
\sum_jP_j^2=\sum_k\left(\sum_js(kj)^2\right)p_k^2+\sum_{k\ne\ell}\left(\sum_js(kj)s(\ell j)\right)p_kp_\ell,
$$
and the trick works if
$$
\sum_js(kj)s(\ell j)=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}1&\text{if}&k=\ell\\ 0&\text{if}&k\ne\ell\end{array}\right.
$$
As is well known, these conditions are met when $s$ is based on the sine function in the sense that, for some suitable angle $\theta$ and factor $\kappa$,
$$
s(m)=\kappa\sin(m\theta),
$$
hence the formulas for $P_j$ in your post.

---

Now we are ready to consider the second type of Hamiltonian in the question, namely,
$$
h_2(q)=\sum_k(q_k-q_{k-1})^2=2\sum_kq_k^2-2\sum_kq_kq_{k-1}.
$$
The first part of the RHS is liable to the same analysis as before hence we are left with
$$
h_3(q)=-2\sum_kq_kq_{k-1}.
$$
Of course, one cannot have
$$
h_3(q)=\sigma\sum_jQ_j^2,\quad\text{where}\quad Q_j=\sum_kq_ks(kj),
$$
for the same family $s$ as above and some parameter $\sigma$, but it happens that one can obtain
$$
h_3(q)=\sum_j\sigma_jQ_j^2,
$$
for some specific family $(\sigma_j)$. The same computations as before show that this happens when
$$
\sum_j\sigma_js(kj)s(\ell j)=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}0&\text{if}&k=\ell\\ -1&\text{if}&k=\ell\pm1\\ 0&\text{if}&|k-\ell|\geqslant2\end{array}\right.
$$
that is, using the addition formula for cosines, when
$$
\sum_j\sigma_j=0,\quad\sum_j\sigma_j\cos(j\theta)=1,\quad\sum_j\sigma_j\cos(rj\theta)=0\quad(r\geqslant2),
$$
hence
$\sigma_j=\sigma_0\cos(j\theta)$ solves this, for some suitable positive $\sigma_0$.

---

Finally, once one understands that the parameter $\omega^2$ in your question ought to be replaced by a family $(\omega_j^2)$, one gets
$$
\sum_k(q_k-q_{k-1})^2=\sum_j\omega_j^2Q_j^2,\quad\text{where}\quad\omega_j^2=2+2\sigma_j,
$$
hence
$$
2H(q,p)=\sum_kp_k^2+(q_k-q_{k-1})^2=\sum_jP_j^2+\omega_j^2Q_j^2.
$$